# Ways to Hide Outdoor Wire box for Outdoor Wall Light

Tags: wiring, garage, outdoor, light

The lights outside the garage are mounted on top of the wire box. It doesn't look great and also allows for water behind the lights.

What would be some good options for solving this?  Putting something around the box or some recessing them?  The current light went bad, so before I replace it, I would like to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Recessing so that the face of the box is flush mount would be best. My guess is that it wasn't done that way originally because making a small hole for wires/conduit was easy but cutting a big hole for a box was either hard (e.g., brick or concrete behind the stucco) or unsafe (right on top of a stud or joist.

Comment: yeah, I think it's concrete and I wonder if there is something that prevented them from doing that.  Any idea how I would recess?

Comment: is that called a wirebox?  I'm thinking of doing decorative wood around it.  but haven't been able to find any examples online.

Comment: Typically called a "junction box", though there are other names.

Comment: You could probably find a new lamp that had a back flange more similar to the existing junction box. Then a combination of foam gasket and caulk would probably weatherproof it. Now my opinion: water probably isn't that big a deal, given the sheltered location. Aesthetics -- that's for you to decide. If you can't find a lamp with a good base, the simplest thing would be to take a 2x8, 10" long and put a hole in the middle to go over the junction box. If the thickness isn't perfect, you can find jboxes 1-5/8" deep, so you could swap that. Be sure to prime all sides of the wood before you mount.

Comment: Yeah, what's behind that stucco?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's concrete.

Comment: I very much understand the concept that _you_ know it's there and, therefore, _you_ see it every time you look at the garage door. I have to wonder, though, how often _others_ see it and think it looks weird. Granted, it's your house and you probably see it daily, but consider the effort to cut into the concrete to recess the box vs the return you'll get by doing so.

Comment: @FreeMan Yeah you are correct.  I doubt anyone else notices.